# $f$ analytic and $|f|\leq1$ on a strip.

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $E$ be the strip $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<\Re z <1\}$. Let $f$ be analytic on $E$ and continuous on $\bar{E}$. Show that if $f$ is bounded on $E$ and $|f|\leq1$ on the boundary of $E$, then $|f|\leq1$ on $E$.

The hint that comes with the problem says to consider the analytic function $f_{\epsilon}(z)=(1+\epsilon z)^{-1}f(z)$ on open set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<\Re z<1, -M<\Im z<M\}$ for $M$ large.

From some searching, it looks like I need to use Möbius transformation but I'm not sure how to integrate that in this case. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Another way one might approach this problem is by using a mobius transformation to map the right half plane to the unit disk then apply maximum modulus principle. The map should be \begin{equation} \frac{z+1}{z-1} \end{equation} I would attempt this because we can apply the maximum modulus principle on the unit disk, so I want to transform his onto a problem on the unit disk.

Comment: Actually we cannot apply Maximum modulus principle in its raw form: the reason is that $f$ cannot be continuously extended to the closure of the domain. The problem arises from the fact that $x\pm i\infty$ is mapped to $1$. Unless one deals with the behavior of $f$ near $1$, maximum modulus principle does not give the result. Most likely, it only makes the problem more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Phragmen-Lindelof principle. Note that 
$$
\lim_{|y|\to\infty} |f_\epsilon(x+iy)| = 0
$$ uniformly on $x\in [0,1]$. If we apply maximum modulus principle to the region
$$
\{x+iy\;|\;0\leq x\leq 1,\;|y|\leq M\}
$$ for large $M>0$, we can see that the maximum modulus of $|f_\epsilon|$ cannot occur on $y=\pm M$. Thus it must occur on the sides $x=0$ or $x=1$. This gives
$$
|f_\epsilon(x+iy)|\leq 1,\quad\forall x\in[0,1],\;|y|\leq M,
$$ for all sufficiently large $M>0$ and thus
$$
|f_\epsilon(x+iy)|\leq 1,\quad\forall x\in [0,1], y\in \mathbb{R}.
$$ Finally take $\epsilon\to 0$ to get the desired bound
$$
|f(x+iy)|\leq 1,\quad\forall x\in [0,1], y\in \mathbb{R}.
$$